# compiling libspeex for symbian

Tags: qt, symbian, speex

I want to use libspeex library in my nokia Qt application. How do I compile speex for this purpose, and how do i add it to my qt project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check the [README file](http://svn.xiph.org/trunk/speex/README.symbian) for Symbian?

If you manage to compile it, basically you just need to add a line like this in your .pro file:

```
symbian:LIBS += c:/path/to/library/speex.lib
```

(or whatever the resulting library is called).